# How can I "unshift" a 1D array into each el of a 2D array?

Tags: javascript

Given `ar1`, how can I iterate through `ar2` and `unshift()` `ar1` having this repeated at the beginning of `a2` as a result?

```js
let ar1 = [4, "Purchase Order", "Yoga"];
let ar2 = [
  ["221123-B", 1, "006"],
  ["221123-C", 1, "006"],
  ["221123-D", 1, "006"],
  ["221123-E", 1, "006"]
]

ar2.forEach(function(el, i) {
  el = ar2[i].unshift(ar1)
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(ar2));
```

**Expected Result**:

```
[
  [4, "Purchase Order", "Yoga", "221123-B", 1, "006"],
  [4, "Purchase Order", "Yoga", "221123-C", 1, "006"],
  [4, "Purchase Order", "Yoga", "221123-D", 1, "006"],
  [4, "Purchase Order", "Yoga", "221123-E", 1, "006"]
]
```

Comment: spread operator might help or `el = ar2[i].unshift(...ar1)` if i understand correct

Comment: please clarify more that what you want actually?

Comment: Thanks your comments. Added the expected result, @jerry.

Comment: @onit even shorter `ar2 = ar2.map(e => [...ar1,...e])`

Comment: Remove the `el =` part, and then just spread the `ar1` when unshifting